# select grid cells by polygon

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

For a small program I'm building I have the following situation:
I have a (rectangular) grid with the boundaries of the grid cells on for example:
x = 50 * nx
with: 0 <= nx <= 100

and y = 100 * ny
with -50 <= ny <= 50

The cell centers (since it is a rectangular grid) are therefor to be found on:
xc = 25 + 50 * nxc (with: 0 <= nxc <= 99)
xc = 50 + 100 * nyc (with: -50 <= nyc <= 49)

(nx, ny, nxc, nyc are integers ofcourse)

Having this grid I want to be able to "draw" a polygon and select all the cells (or cell centers) that are inside this polygon. How would one approach this?

An example polygon would be

[image: Example grid: x axis (0, 200, 400, etc.) y axis (0, 500, 100, 1500, etc)]

```
x     y
400   -200
1000  2500
2000  1500
1800  -300
1000  -100
500   -2000
```

The drawn shape (polygon) is just an example, it can be any shape. The polygon that defines the shape does however not have lines that cross eachother.

The (rectangular) grid can also be of any arbitrary size but the locations of the grid boundaries and their cell centers are known.

So how does one determine the cells (or cell centers) that are inside the polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia offers a good trick to decide whether a point is inside or outside the polygon. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Basically choose an arbitrary line that goes through a point in the cell of interest to count how many intersections it has with the polygon. Even number -> outside, odd number -> inside. Since all polygon segments are known, this would be trivial. Be careful, if there is a mathematical intersection with the equation, make sure the intersection is actually on the segment. If (a1,b1) (a2,b2) represents the segment and (x,y) represents the intersection, make sure x is between a1 and a2, and y is between b1 and b2.

That said, to determine if a cell is within the polygon, you will need all its 4 corners to be in the polygon, otherwise the cell is either partially or entirely outside the polygon.

Edit:

To make answer more complete to cover the concave case like below where all four corners are in the polygon, but not all of the cell body is.
[image]
One way to check concavity is to, instead of an arbitrary line, choose the four sides of a cell to see if there are >= 2 intersections on any of the four sides. If yes, it could be a sign of concavity, and then it really depends on your definition of inside or outside.

---

Comment: It's even possible for all 4 corners of the cell to be in the polygon but for the entire cell not to be contained in the polygon.  (Unless the polygon is convex, of course.)

Comment: That is true. One way to check that is to, instead of an arbitrary line, choose the four sides of the cell to see if there are >= 2 intersections on any of the four sides. If yes, then it would be this complicated scenario.